# 550 Relay Denied in Xmail

Tags: smtp

I am running Xmail server in Windows 2003. When I took SMTP test at MxToolBox.com I am getting an error as `550 Relay Denied`. How to fix this error?

`SMTPrelay.tab` file contains the following.

`"65.75.241.26" "255.255.255.0"` The syntax shout be as `"<IP><tab><SubMask>"` But why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is no error. This is by intention! If you ever *fix* this error everybody is going to *kill* you.

You are not allowed to create an open relay in the Internet. And MxToolbox confirms that you do not have one.